# Inverse function theorem differentiation question

Tags: real-analysis

Q: Given that the function $f:[0,\pi]\rightarrow[-1,1]$ given by $$f(x)=\cos(x)$$ for each $x\in[0,\pi]$ is continuous and strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi]$, and therefore the inverse function $f^{-1}:[-1,1]\rightarrow[0,\pi]$ is well defined.

(i) Fix $x_0\in(0,\pi)$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $$f'(x_0)=-\sin(x_0)$$

(ii) Fix $y_0\in(-1,1)$. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y_0$ and $$(f^{-1})'(y_0)=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-y_0^2}}$$

I need help on part ii. This is what I have got but I am unsure whether it needs more justification or reordering.

(ii) Our function $f$ satisfies the conditions of the Inverse Function Theorem and there exists $y_0=f(x_0)$ so $y_0=\cos(x_0)$. Since we know by (i) that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)=-\sin(x_0)\neq0$, then by theorem $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $y_0$ and $$(f^{-1})'(y_0)=\frac1{f'(x_0)}=-\frac1{\sin(x_0)}$$

Notice that $$ y_0=\cos(x_0) \iff y_0^2=\cos^2(x_0)=1-\sin^2(x_0) \iff \sin(x_0)=\sqrt{1-y_0^2} $$
$\therefore$
$$(f^{-1})'(y_0)=\frac1{f'(x_0)}=-\frac1{\sin(x_0)}=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-y_0^2}}$$

My lecturer is VERY strict on justification so please advise me.

Comment: You're missing the derivative sign everywhere on (ii), in the question and in the answer. I find hard to believe that someone would consider this insufficiently justified, but perhaps you should add a note explaining why you abandoned the negative square roots.

Comment: alright will do. thanks